# Covert stringified object of array to object in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, express

I'm sending stringified data from Angular using FormData like:

```
this.formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(this.collections))
```

How can I convert it back to object in my backend (Express)?
I'm getting data in `req.body` .

This is what I'm receiving in `req.body.data`:

```
[{"uid":"","description":"store","price":"777"},{"uid":"dd5adebf-06c6-4d6c-b005-2fcb0a2ca161","description":"blanketssdf","price":""}]
```

I cannot use `application/json` header since I'm using `mutipart/form-data` to send images.

I'm stuck at this since long. I've tried JSON.parse(), Object.assign() but nothing works.
`console.dir()` gives me the desired result but I want this result to be stored so that I can perform stuff on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im not so sure whats ur problem, it looks like a valid json, all you have to do is JSON.parse().
Show us your code to see whats the problem

Comment: @Talg123 Problem is I think is because I'm not using `application/json`. This is the code for sending data and data received/

Answer (score 0):

I had it done using `JSON.parse(new Object(req.body.data))`